# An isometry in Hilbert space that is not surjective

Tags: field-theory

Let $l^2$ be the space of infinite sequences
$(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{F}$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i|^2 < \infty$.  We define the norm on $l^2$ via the inner product $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i \overline{y_i}$. Define
$$
S[(x_1,x_2,\dots)] = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots)
$$
This mapping is isometry. But I am unable to show that it is not surjective as somewhere I am getting confused about how to find an element from codomain whose pre-image is not in domain of S.

Comment: If $x_1 \ne 0$, then $x = (x_1, x_2, \dotsc)$ is not in the range of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $(1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2^2}, \dots)$ as an explicit element. More generally, any element with nonzero first term will do.